# How to give one hot Encoding for Categorical Values for Labels in Estimator Classification in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I have a Dataset in which I have String Values in Labels for Classification. I have Loaded the Dataset in Tensorflow and have Defined the Feature Columns for Different Features. Since I also have Categorical Data in Labels, So how can Give them.one hot Encoding so that the Estimator.LinearClassifier can Learn The Data and Predict the Label?

Comment: Since you're using tensorflow, an option would be to use `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical`. It handily converts your target (Labels) vector into a binary class matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas. Assuming you already have your non categorical features in dataFrame 'df'.

Use can use this:

```
import pandas as pd
featurelist_categorical = ['Feature A',
           'Feature B']

for i,j in zip(featurelist_categorical, ['A','B']):
  df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(data[i],prefix=j)], axis=1)
```

The feature prefix is not necessary but will help you specially in case of multiple categorical features.

Also if you don't want to split your features into numbers for some reason you can use H2O.ai. With H2O you can directly feed categorical variables into models as text.